# Prevent users from downloading and using my Java applet manually

Tags: java, security, applet

I've written a Java Applet and run it from my website.

In the long-term I plan to charge money per use of this applet.

The question is, is it possible to prevent users of downloading my code (i.e. my jar file) and  then running it from their home, without paying?

(In this I don't mean decompile - I use obfuscator. I mean someone can use it easily without even decompiling it or understand it's code...)

I thought about using a changing password which the server sends to the applet using the HTML, but I thought - maybe someone knows a standard way of achieving my goal instead of reinventing the wheel??

Thanks..

Comment: You should be able to check what domain it's running under.  There are also things like single-use tokens you can provide via html to the applet which the applet then checks with the server

Comment: Can I have a link to your website? I want to see whether this applet is good enough to be worth paying to use it.

Answer (score 5):

There are several ways you can do this.

1. You can put code like this at the beginning of the applet's `init` method, assuming it creates some components:

   ```
   if (!getDocumentBase().getHost().equals("yourhost.com")) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "You can't download it");
       return;
   }
   ```

   Of course, you have to change `yourhost.com` to your actual website.

   #### Pros:

   - Easy to implement, no server-side code

   #### Cons:

   - Can be decompiled and the test can be removed
   - Someone could trick their computer into thinking it is "yourhost.com"
2. You can put all of your code on the server. For this, I will assume that your applet computes the cube of an integer.

   Then the code looks like this for your applet:

   ```
   public class CubingApplet extends JApplet {
       private JTextField intField = new JTextField(3);
       private JLabel output = new JLabel();

       public void init() {
           setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
           add(new JLabel("Enter an integer: "));
           add(intField);
           add(new JLabel("The cube of that is: ");
           add(output);
           intField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                   output.setText("" + getCube());
               }
           };
       }

       private int getCube() {
           try {
               int n = Integer.parseInt(intField.getText());
               InputStream response = new URL("http://www.yourhost.com/dosomething.php?n=" + n).openStream();
               String sResponse = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response)).readLine();
               return Integer.parseInt(sResponse);
           } catch (Exception e) {
               throw new RuntimeException(e);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   I must stop writing this right now, but I will add server-side code at the earliest opportunity.

By the way, even if you obfuscate, and it can't be decompiled, it is possible to recognize what these kinds of protection schemes look like, and remove them. So any protection scheme you devise can be short-circuited, because no obfuscation is bulletproof.

Comment: Of course someone could embed this in their own page and set their hosts file to point `yourhost.com` at their server.

Answer (score 3):

If the user's computer does all of the work of the applet, then it is impossible to prevent them from downloading a copy of the code. The browser has to download the code in order to run it; all the user needs to do is tell the browser to save the file or to use another program that will. The only way to prevent the user from being able to use the applet offline is with DRM. Perhaps you can include a check to your servers to ensure that the usage is valid; while the program is free the usage would always be valid but later you could verify it online. This is vulnerable to decompilation and modification to remove the DRM. Another option is to do some of the computation on your server, using code that is never exposed, but this of course has the downside of requiring you to maintain servers to do the calculations, which can be expensive.

Answer (score 1):

In short no.  Anyone can look at the webpages source code, find where the applet is stored and directly download it.  If your product is not limited to an applet then it would probably be better to have it as an executable and sell that.

If you *really* need for it to be an applet that is payed for every time without being downloadable you could run all the actual processing on a separate server, construct what the screen would look like on the server and then send that image to the client (whos is using the applet).  You would then display that image on the applet.  Bear in mind that if your program would accept user input the applet would have to send that input to the server to be processed to.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this would be to have a program on the serverside that provides data that is necessary for the app to do anything useful. They are only allowed to connect the applet to this if they have purchased an account (they have to log in inside the applet).

Since this is enforced serverside, they cannot bypass the restriction.

This obviates the problem of them downloading and decompiling it, because they still have to have an account to make any use of the applet.

The downside is that will probably require some rewriting of the applet and the creation of an entirely new program for the server.

Answer (score 1):

If you really wish to protect your source code, you can make use of **J2EE** and make servlets that run on your webserver. The great thing about this is that all the work is done server-sided, similar to using **PHP**. This means that the end user can only see the output of the program and can not access the program files themselves.

A great article to read on the subject of J2EE servlets can be found here:
[Java Servlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Servlet)

Here is a quote from that page, I think it is exactly what you are looking for:

> The servlet is a Java programming language class used to extend the capabilities of a server. Although servlets can respond to any types of requests, they are commonly used to extend the applications hosted by web servers, so they can be thought of as Java Applets that run on servers instead of in web browsers.

Answer (score 0):

If you will implement a login page before the user will be able to use the applet, then you will not need to prevent them from downloading it. Anyone who wants to use must register (buy) from you a username/password.

Additionally you have already using obfuscator to prevent decompiling, which means that it will not  be that easy to modify the applet to bypass login.